# how to calculate nearby peoples list within 200 meters in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, gps

I want to show list of nearby peoples. how to make loop which calculate all database latitude and longitude and give me nearby peoples list so i can send notifications to them. which api helps for this? and how to implement all these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

This plugin has a method to calculate distance between two position

```
double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(startLatitude,startLongitude,endLatitude,endLongitude);
```

You can make a loop for checking nearby people

```
for (var person in people) {
      double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(thisLatitude,thisLongitude,person.Latitude,person.Longitude);
      if(distanceInMeters<=200){
        notification();
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain 'var person in people' means? and how can i fetch different users locations from firestore?

Comment: I got your answer, but what if I want to run some method when I find the nearest person

Comment: So this mean, if I have 5 million users on earth, then do I need to Iterate through 5 million data each user request / accessing my app, which is not effective

Comment: @PhilipPurwoko, then for that case if users are many you should handle that from the API side probably if you use python you can use celery, currently handling it from front end but am moving towards doing so from api, and also you can make use of flutter background processes